# Uniqueness of a function that satisfies a condition

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, laplace-transform

Let $F:[0, \infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty F(t)e^{-st}(-1+st)dt=\frac{1}{s^2}.
\end{align}
One possibility to solve the previous problem is to have $F(t)=t$ (I can see the integral as an expectation respect to an exponential distribution).
There exists another function $F$ that satisfies that condition?

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty F(t)(-1+st)e^{-st}\,dt&=-\int_0^\infty F(t)e^{-st}\,dt-s\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty F(t)e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=-sf'(s)-f(s)\\\\
&=-(sf(s))'\tag1
\end{align}$$

where $f(s) =\int_0^\infty F(t)e^{-st}\,dt$ is the Laplace Transform of $F$.

Setting the right-hand side of $(1)$ equal to $\frac{1}{s^2}$, we find by integrating that

$$f(s)=\frac1{s^2}+\frac{C}{s}\tag2$$

where $C$ is an integration constant.

Taking the inverse Laplace Transform of $(2)$, we find that

$$F(t) =t+C$$

for any constant $C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think that it could  exist a non linear function that satisfies that condition?

Comment: If $F(t)$ is continuous and of exponential order, then its Laplace Transform exists and is unique.  So, this is the only such function.

Comment: You are right , thank you!

Comment: Another thing, from the result is clear that $C=F(0)$. Can I see it when I integrate in (1)?

Comment: $F(0)$ is unspecified and is arbitrary.   That is, any value of $C$ works here.